# Why 是 is in 所以山门中是冷请了些 ？

Tags: grammar

In 所以山门中是冷清了些。 why 是 is used between a noun as 山门中 and an adjective as 冷清 ？

If for that purpose (connect nouns an adjectives) we have 很 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

山门中(noun) +是(verb) +冷清了(adj) +些(adv, modify/quantify 冷清)

Depending on the overall context, 是 can either be "is", or "has (became)".

很 means "very" or "much", which conflicts with 些 - "some", "a few", "a little", "a bit".

Answer (score 1):

是 indicates here an emphasis on affirmation and can be understood as "indeed".

Answer (score 0):

是 here is a straightforward "is"

山门 (gate) 中 (inside)

所以山门中(是)冷清了些 = Therefore inside the gate (is) a bit deserted

Similar example

大海[很危險] = The sea [is dangerous]

大海[是][危險的] = The sea [is] [dangerous]

大海[是][很危險] = The sea [is] [very dangerous]

大海[是][很危險的] = The sea [is] [very dangerous]

Note: *大海[是][危險] = The sea [is] [danger] or The sea [is] [dangerous] because 危險 without 的 can be a noun or adjective*

Answer (score 0):

I think 山门 may be a 佛寺，but also may be a 道观。

Either way, you may write:

1. 所以山门中是冷清了些。
   Therefore, there are indeed not many people in the temple.

or

2. 所以山门中很是冷清了些。

but people I ask will not accept:

3. 所以山门中很冷清了些。

I think that is because the 些 means 'a little' or 'somewhat' so then you would have the combination of 'very *something* a little,' which is a kind of contradiction.